# Is it possible to store large file in Spring Boot in Postgres Db as InputStream

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, inputstream

I am using Spring boot application. I want to store more number of image/pdf files. Each file size be 20 mb approx.

**Current Class:**

```
Class StoreFile {

   @Lob
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")
    @Column(name = "file", nullable = false, length=20000000)
    private byte[] file;
}
```

I had set the type as **Inputstream** instead of **byte[]** as below and got below exception when storing the file.

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Value was
> not an array

```
Class StoreFile {

   @Lob
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")
    @Column(name = "file", nullable = false, length=20000000)
    private InputStream file;
}
```

How to store the large size files in Postgres DB in an efficient way? Can we store it as Inputstream in Database?

Comment: Input stream is, as the name suggests, a stream. So you can't store it in the database. In other words, it is not a finite data structure, it is a stream of data.

Comment: @DragoslavPetrovic How can we convert stream to byte[] and store in database in an efficient manner in Spring?

Comment: "The java.sql.Blob interface provides you with multiple methods to get an InputStream or a byte[] of the BLOB value." [ref](https://thorben-janssen.com/mapping-blobs-and-clobs-with-hibernate-and-jpa/)

Comment: the "most efficient" is probably: to use [tag:spring-jdbc] with [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/jdbc-binary-data.html) `PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(...)`..